# Chrome extensions popups stopped displaying correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

All popups from extensions were working correctly until recently.

I fiddled a bit with the .css of neater bookmarks extension (in users/.../chrome/user data/default/extensions/...) trying to increase its height. Increased height, but scrollbars appeared so I just undid all the changes and saved the .css.

Not sure when, but shortly after ALL popups from ALL extensions displayed a small empty box instead of their usual function:

Screenshots

[image]

Inspecting them (inspect group) shows no error, and on the "Elements" tab I can see the html just fine, it seems to be loading ok, just not displaying.

I tried disabling ALL extensions, restarting Chrome and re-enabling them. Completely  removing extensions and then re-installing just one to check. Re-installing latest (dev) Chrome. Emptying Chrome cache. Nothing worked.
I am on Version 27.0.1430.3 dev-m. Can't think of anything else to do.

Any ideas on what could be the issue? Or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: This issue have been identified in the dev channel, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180378 Not sure if they have any timeline for a fix.